# border - 100% height of parent div

Tags: html, css

here is the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Rpdr9/2175/

i got 2 inline divs  with bootstrap

i want to add a border between them with 100 % height of parent div :

now it's equal to card size(yellow thing)
How can i do this ?

```
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body all">

            <div class="row clear">
                <div class="col-md-2 sp-right border-right">

                    <div class="tbTile yellow sp-inline">
                            <span> phase</span>                  
                    </div>                  
                </div>
    </div>

            <div class="col-md-10 sp-right "> Something </div>
    </div>
```

[image]

Comment: yes , but that was unclear

Comment: would you plz help instead of unvoted ?

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your `div` in a wrapper `div` and use a pseudo element to get the middle border.

Something like:

```css
html,body{height:100%;
margin:0;padding:0;}
.wrap {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: gray;
}
.wrap:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-right: 5px solid black;
}
.left{
  width:49%;
  min-height:50px;
  background:tomato;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  }
.right{
  width:49%;
  min-height:150px;
  background:blue;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  }
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

---

Your Fiddle updated:

[can be seen here](http://jsfiddle.net/Rpdr9/2180/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Rpdr9/2178/ , this is with your soloution, but i want to cover it in red border

Comment: @Sani: I had a typo- in my .wrap class add a ; after the word relative.

Comment: ok but still it's not the thing i'm looking for,
check this : http://jsfiddle.net/Rpdr9/2179/

Comment: @sani: please see updated fiddle in answer - it should be what you're looking for :) :)

Comment: thanks but it's not the best way, don't mess with body

Comment: @sani: place it on the outer-most container that you want to add the line to. I saw the body was outer-most so presumed that was the container in which you were referring to. If it is not, then apply said styling to the container of your choice. Notice the properties I've copy and pasted/used and apply this to whichever element you want to apply it to.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78629/discussion-between-sani-and-professor-css).